# How to calculate someone's true net worth?

Tags: income-tax, mortgage, income, net-worth

Is there a way I can look up or calculate another person's net worth through math? Is a person who is making credit card, car, house, etc payments owe more that what they have equal they are worth less then nothing?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if they give you a list of assets and liabilities, you can calculate any person's net worth by adding up all the assets and subtracting all the liabilities from the total.

Comment: @Muze I answered exactly the question you initially asked. Your edits make your question less clear. Yes, your net worth can be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they're on forbes' list, you probably won't be able to look up someone's net worth (it's also extremely private information). it's just value of assets - value of liabilities.... If you have those numbers it's fairly easy (mint used to actually display it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not answer +1 could use more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating someone's true [net worth](https://richpeoplenetworth.com/) involves adding up all their assets and subtracting their liabilities. Here's a step-by-step guide

1. Make a list of all the things they own that have value, like money
   in the bank, investments, houses, cars, and valuable possessions.
2. Figure out how much each of those things is worth. This might
   involve looking at bank statements, checking the stock market, or
   getting an appraisal for houses or valuable items.
3. Add up the values of all the things they own. This gives you the
   total value of their assets.
4. Make a list of all the money they owe, such as mortgages, loans,
   credit card debt, and any other debts.
5. Figure out exactly how much they owe for each of those debts. You
   can find this information on loan statements, credit card bills, or
   by contacting lenders.
6. Add up the amounts owed for all the debts. This gives you the total
   amount of their liabilities.
7. Finally, subtract the total amount of liabilities from the total
   value of assets. The result is their net worth.

**Net Worth = Total Value of Assets - Total Amount of Liabilities**